# BufferedReader readline reading null even though there is text in the file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

Basically, I'm trying to create a simple database app with automatically generated IDs in each student entry. The program reads the previous highest ID and adds 1 to it to create the next one.
However, even though the text document has numbers in it, BufferedReader keeps returning null when using readLine

I checked if my int parsing was the issue, but i realized it was the bufferedreader by saving the readline to a variable then printing it, where I got the result of null. I also tried using scanner file reading which didn't work, and I checked all related classes and methods to try to figure it out.

This code creates the topsid file and writes 0 to initialize it, which is being read as null

```
if(MiscProcesses.firstStartup() == false) //method that checks if these files exist
{
                File topsid = new File("topsid.txt");
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(topsid);
                fw.write("0");
                fw.close();
}
```

This code is responsible for reading the file and hence finding a higher id value

```
Student (String[] studata) 
{
            //checking highest SID
            File topsid = new File("topsid.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(topsid);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(topsid);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


            //checking high sid file and getting new sid
            String test = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(test+" <test");   <this ends up printing null

            int sid;

            sid = Integer.parseInt(test)+1;
            System.out.println(sid);

            fw.write(Integer.toString(sid));
            this.id = sid;

            ...

            br.close();
            fr.close();
            fw.close();       
 }
```

When I open the topsid file before the second code runs, it's all fine and the file contains a zero.
I would expect the bufferedreader to read "0" but it just reads null, and when I open the file after the code runs, the data inside gets erased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(topsid);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(topsid);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Creating the `FileWriter` like this will stomp the existing file before you read its contents.

If you want to read something from the file, then write something back after, create the `FileWriter` *after* you have read from it.